# C# - How to set up a small Mdi "area" for MdiChildren?

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I have a Mdi parent form and some Mdi child forms. It works good so far but I want to define a smaller area on the parent form where the Mdi children can be moved around. It looks like the property `MdiParent` is of type `Form`. Now I wonder how can I make the children move inside a **specific area** but not inside the whole parent window.

```
class MdiParentForm: Form
{
    public MdiParentForm()
    {
        this.IsMdiContainer = true;
        Form form = new Form();
        this.AddOwnedForm(form);
        form.MdiParent = this;
        form.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just set the `Padding` of your `Mdi` form. The padding is the distance between the control (as a container) and its child controls. There are 4 sides: left, top, right, bottom. This code just makes all the sides the same:

```
Padding = new Padding(50);
```

You can notice that the `BackColor` around the `MdiClient` is not affected. To affect the `BackColor` around the `MdiClient`, we have to override the `OnPaint` so that the default behavior is not processed:

```
BackColor = Color.Green;//try setting the BackColor of the Mdi form to Color.Green
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e){
   RaisePaintEvent(this, e); //remove the base.OnPaint(e)
}
```

If you want to take full control over the `MdiClient`, just declare a variable to hold the `MdiClient`:

```
MdiClient client = Controls.OfType<MdiClient>().First();
```

Then you can use its `Properties` and `methods` like as you do on a form, such as `client.Dock = DockStyle.Left`, `client.Width = 400;`, ...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is automatic when you Dock other controls to the edges of the MDI parent form.  The dark-gray MDI client window shrinks to fit the remaining space.  Using the Dock property is the essential part.